# "lui fit bien augurer de" or "le fit bien augurer de"?

Tags: grammaire, constructions-causatives

I came across a sentence that gave me a slight grammar-nerd pause, and wanted to double check my intuition:

> Cette bonne volonté impressionna favorablement le patron et lui fit bien augurer du succès de l'expédition.

Given that it's augurer *de*, I would have expected this faire causatif to read *le* fit bien augurer de. I've tried searching google for other examples and find many of both, *le* and *lui*, so now I'm curious which sounds more idiomatic/grammatical to a native speaker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only valid pronoun is ***lui*** here.

It refers to ***le patron***, a person, and is an indirect object of the verb *faire augurer* (*faire augurer **à qui***?).

> La bonne volonté parut de bon augure **au patron**.

In ***le** fit augurer*, the pronoun ***le*** would have referred to what is "*auguré*" (*faire augurer **quoi**?*):

> *Que l'expédition soit un succès, cette bonne volonté impressionnante **le** fit augurer (au patron)*.

Here ***le*** refers to ***le succès de l'expédition***.